# How to do fast nearest-neighbor upsampling in Theano?

Tags: resize, theano

Currently I am using this code, but it is really slow:

```
def resizeNN(inp, scale):
    b, ch, row, col = inp.shape
    out = T.zeros((b, ch, row * scale, col * scale))
    for y range(scale):
      for x range(scale):
        out = T.inc_subtensor(out[:, :, y::scale, x::scale], inp)

    return out
```

Is there any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is more vectorized. I'm not sure how fast this is due to reshape.

```
def resizeNN(inp, scale):
    inp_shp = T.shape(inp)
    return T.tile(inp.dimshuffle(0,1,2,3,'x','x'),
        (scale,scale)).transpose(
            0,1,2,4,3,5).reshape(
                inp_shp[0], inp_shp[1],
                inp_shp[2]*scale, inp_shp[3]*scale)
```